# Presenting The "Worst" Accepted Answers

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

A comment in an answer asks for the "worst" accepted answers... so here they are. Presented without comment.

This data is from a query I've copied and modified: https://data.stackexchange.com/workplace/query/1667582

| Link | Year | Up | Down | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [How can I deal with my coworkers using unknown jargon and acronyms?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/148770) | 2019 | 37 | 64 | -27 |
| [Accidentally spent much more than the food allowance on a business trip](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/187898) | 2022 | 11 | 32 | -21 |
| [Company threatening to call my current job after I declined their offer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/139160) | 2019 | 21 | 38 | -17 |
| [Commanding respect as the manager after an unfortunate, and embarrassing, incident at work](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/87445) | 2017 | 1 | 15 | -14 |
| [As a contractor should I bill my hours even if there's no work?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/127645) | 2019 | 1 | 12 | -11 |
| [Confidentiality around heads up notice](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/186679) | 2022 | 1 | 7 | -6 |
| [Did my colleague use a racial slur, or is this use of the word acceptable?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/145395) | 2019 | 2 | 7 | -5 |
| [In a Scrum shop who calls the deployment?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/182629) | 2022 | 0 | 4 | -4 |
| [Excluded from extra work activities](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/162830) | 2020 | 12 | 15 | -3 |
| [How to deal with a colleague with poor Slack etiquette?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/186646) | 2022 | 1 | 4 | -3 |
| [Request for increment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/129649) | 2019 | 1 | 4 | -3 |
| [Mistake during internship](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/171500) | 2021 | 1 | 4 | -3 |
| [How should I interpret a comment made by a member of management at my new job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/128643) | 2019 | 2 | 5 | -3 |
| [How can I ask for a quote breakdown - when agency refuses?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/166549) | 2020 | 1 | 4 | -3 |
| [How can I stop my colleagues being disrespectful about my personal life choices?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/46885) | 2015 | 8 | 10 | -2 |
| [How do I deal with HR/recruiter pre-screeners who seem unsatisfied with succinct answers?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/10724) | 2013 | 2 | 4 | -2 |
| [How can a subcontractor or temporary agency comply with the Americans with Disabilities Act (ADA)?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/46996) | 2015 | 2 | 4 | -2 |
| [Wanting to work somewhere with an option to move, should I tell recruiter?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/125374) | 2018 | 0 | 1 | -1 |
| [How to prepare team for layoff?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/163186) | 2020 | 3 | 4 | -1 |
| [Displaying a corporate website on web portfolio](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/41715) | 2014 | 1 | 2 | -1 |
| [When is it worth pointing out an error on another person's part?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/115271) | 2018 | 2 | 3 | -1 |
| [Negotiating an Offer: Salary vs. Equity + Signing Bonus. Help!](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/151879) | 2020 | 0 | 1 | -1 |
| [how should I list concurrent freelance and staff jobs on LinkedIn experience?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/91032) | 2017 | 0 | 1 | -1 |
| [How to ask a busy volunteer to response to an urgent task?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/158509) | 2020 | 1 | 2 | -1 |
| [My employer is demanding that, as a teacher, I have my webcam on all the day, do I have to comply?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/157397) | 2020 | 5 | 6 | -1 |

Comment: Folks often accept an answer that agrees with their thinking. It's no surprise that on a gamified site like this, others might not agree.

Comment: So by "worst", it appears that you mean "lowest score" for an accepted answer. I suppose there could be lots of alternative definitions of "worst". For example, "the largest score difference between the accepted answer and the highest-scoring answer".

Comment: "My employer is demanding that, as a teacher, I have my webcam on all the day, do I have to comply?" - is now sitting at -5. and has 8 more total votes than reported in your query. Odd

Comment: @JoeStrazzere possibly people read this question, went to look at the original Q&A and further downvoted the bad answers. I'm guessing all of them will end up more-downvoted than before.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Yeah. It's why I put worst in quotes. I know the word is very subjective. Not sure why some of the numbers are not accurate though... Maybe my query needs a tweak.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I just checked the data returned for the last row... The data looks correct, but obviously doesn't match what is displayed. "SELECT * FROM Votes where PostID = 157397" returns 12 rows

Comment: Why not just call them what they are: "accepted answers with more downvotes than upvotes"? As already mentioned, some of these might be great answers, so "worst" is really misleading as well as subjective.

Comment: @terdon I really couldn't care less.

Comment: Regarding the word "worst", a lot of these answers are quite bad and deserving of many downvotes.

Comment: The fourth "worst" one looks like the person making the question also made a new account and wrote the answer and accepted it (The "Commanding Respect" one).  Both have never been seen again since that day for 5 years and 8 months and they only ever interacted with that one question.  He even compliments the answer strangely in the comments.

Answer (score 9):

I am going to go out on a limb here and speculate that they all are answers that give the user validation....

Now I will go look and test my theory

Comment: The amiright bias is powerful.